# colworWithPatternImage returning a 1 pixel transparent border

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm trying to create a image with a tiled pattern but the tiled image seems to have a 1 pixel transparent border.  Even when I use just a white background image I still get the transparent border.

```
UIImage *patternImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"whiteimage.png"];
CALayer *layer=[[CALayer alloc] init];
layer.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 2048, 1536);
layer.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:patternImage].CGColor;
UIView *view=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,2048,1536)];
[view setOpaque:YES];
[view.layer addSublayer:layer];
```

Pattern Image
[image: pattern image]

Tiled Image with transparent 1px border
[image: tiled image]

The pattern image was exported from Photoshop using bicubic resampling but I've also tried bilinear and nearest neighbour methods.  Also if I use the image as a pattern in Photoshop I don't get the transparent border which leads me to think it's iOS related.

Comment: Is that actually the pattern image you are using? How come it is so big?

Comment: The white pattern image didn't have to be so big, but the sample I'm using is of similar size.  The tiled image is used to form a floor where it has a perspective transform applied to it so needs to be quite large to fill the floor.

Comment: The above code works fine for me, what else are you doing to the image and view? e.g. How is it that in your second image the tiled images are much smaller?

Comment: Sorry @JamesP I forgot to include my resize function which scaled the image smaller and turned out to be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(UIImage*) resizeImage:(UIImage*)image newSize:(CGSize)newSize
{
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
        [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
        UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();     
        return newImage;
}
```

I forgot to include my helper method in my question which scales the tile image.  It was this method that was giving me the problem.  When I increase the width and height by a pixel I no longer get the transparent border in the returned image.

```
-(UIImage*) resizeImage:(UIImage*)image newSize:(CGSize)newSize
{
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
        [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width+1, newSize.height+1)];
        UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();       
        return newImage;

}
```